# What is the correct URL to use if I'm trying to embed an HLS stream into a webpage where html page is on the same server as the stream?

Tags: javascript, nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js

I'm using the RTMP module built into NGINX to make an HLS stream. I want to embed that stream into an HTML page on the same server.

The stream is working fine when I open it on VLC but when I publish the page to my live web server it's getting blocked.

Here's my html page, it's very basic and runs correctly when I'm viewing it locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
  <title>Camera</title>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Avenir Next Var','Lucida Grande',Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width:960px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h3>Journalism Camera</h3>
    <h4>Emerson College - Boston, MA.</h4>

    <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    autoplay="true"
    muted="true"
    preload="auto"
    width="960"
    height="540"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/hls/livestream1.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/dash/livestream1.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
   
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

</div>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I upload this html page to my live production server I get this error message

````
video.min.js:12 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:2 MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK) HLS playlist request error at URL: http://localhost:8080/hls/livestream1.m3u8. 
_t {code: 2, status: 0, message: 'HLS playlist request error at URL: http://localhost:8080/hls/livestream1.m3u8.', responseText: ''}
VM578:1 GET http://localhost:8080/hls/livestream1.m3u8 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
﻿
​```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your page locally was at `http://localhost:8080/`, you can just use relative paths for your streams:

```
<source src="/hls/livestream1.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
<source src="/dash/livestream1.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
```

Comment: Wish it where that straight forward, but the streams are served on different port and are not in the same directory as the html files.

Comment: You can't have a relative path with a different port. Why not just use an absolute path?

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd Alright, well, use the correct host/port then.  How are we to know where your streams are hosted?  You didn't mention this in your question.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, well basically I that's what I was asking. if I can use `http://localhost:8080` on a page that's hosted on the same server but it's running on port 80 (default) and that page is public. So can www.myserver.com/watchstream.html pull in the http://localhost:8080? It seems to break when I try it right now. (Both are on the same server, just different ports)

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd Ah, so they're using the same hostname, but not the same host (which includes port).  There is no relative URL you can use for this.  You need to use JavaScript in this case to generate the URLs and add the source elements accordingly.

Comment: @Brad Got, it okay that makes sense then. Thanks for the help